# PHP: DOMDocument createElement not work for iframe

Tags: php, html, domdocument, createelement

My code :

```
$span = $doc->createElement('span');

$iframe = $doc->createElement('iframe');
$iframe->setAttribute('src', 'https://www.name.com/frame/aaa');

$newnode = $doc->createElement('div');
$newnode->setAttribute('class', 'h_class');
$newnode->appendChild($span);
$newnode->appendChild($iframe);
```

`$span` added to html but `$iframe` not added

span, p, div and another tag work fine, but iframe tag not work

Comment: It work fine and create iframe, Check https://3v4l.org/ZcFci

Comment: @Mohammad i use `$node->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode, $node);` and not work

Comment: Your problem is `iframe` so why using `replaceChild`?

Comment: @Mohammad because i replace tag `a` with `iframe`. in replace iframe not work

Comment: @Mohammad work fine here : https://3v4l.org/tsJHf . but not work for me

Comment: That mean the code is correct but you code (in local) has problem. Remove other part of codes in your file and then check it and if it works, add other parts one by one and detect cause of problem.

Comment: @Mohammad yeah, i use html purifier and remove it. now work fine. thank you